# Google DistanceMatrix API

Tags: javascript, google-distancematrix-api

I'm trying to get the `direction_in_traffic`, which isn't returned using the regular directions api. I've found that there is a field in the `distancematrix` api that does just that.

This code works when I run it from my own machine, but once it is online, I see errors concerning `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

```
var durationInTraffic = function(from, to, mode, callback) {
  var key = 'API-KEY';
  var address = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' + from + '&destinations=' + to + '&key='+ key +'&travelmode=' + mode + '&departure_time=now';
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
      callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText).rows[0].elements[0].duration_in_traffic.value);
    }
  });

  req.open('GET',address);
  req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://haroen.me');
  req.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With');
  req.send();
};
```

I've created the key, but at the `domain verification` tab it seems to "forget" what addres I've put in.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/moqikajule/1/edit?js,console,output) (which obviously won't work since this key isn't allowed on that domain, but I get the same error on my own domain).

The full code I'm trying this on is visible at https://github.com/haroenv/maps-checker

Thanks for your help!

Comment: May want to hide your API key if it's linked to your actual google dev account.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of that

Comment: you might want to change your key, lots of sites suck up SO posts/revisions (as clicking "editied ... ago" does). also, you should not set CORS headers from client-side JS, those are server response headers.

Comment: @dandavis so is it not possible to use the distancematrix api from a client side then? The `setRequestHeader` I tried didn't actually change anything leading me to believe the error is somewhere else

Comment: from what i could tell from the docs and sample URLs, that API does not seem to support CORS or JSONp, so you'll need a "proxy".

Comment: @dandavis what do you mean by that? Would it be creating a server-side api that "mirrors" each request to google?

Comment: yeah, you ajax your php server and the php talks to the 3rd-party api. this lets you hide keys, bypass CORS, cache, authenticate, etc.

Comment: Aha, that sucks, but thanks for your help! If you'd write this in an answer I'd accept it @dandavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @dandavis suggested in a comment, the reason why this didn't work is because Google wants this response to be server-side. My workaround is as follows: a `php` (or any server-side solution) that mirrors the request to Google. An example implementation is this:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=' . urlencode($_POST['from']) . '&destinations=' . urlencode($_POST['to']) . '&key='. urlencode(json_decode(file_get_contents('config.json'), true)['maps-key']) .'&mode=' . urlencode($_POST['mode']) . '&departure_time=now');
?>
```

And then I send a request to that script from within my main client-side script.